# npm install -g firebase-toolsができない

Tags: firebase, npm

初めまして、現在vue.jsとfirebaseのアプリケーションを作成したいと考えております。

現在npm install -g firebase-toolsがうまくできません。

以下エラー文です

```
^Cmbp:firebase-training hidakarento$ npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-
tools
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-
tools/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase
-tools'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/fire
base-tools']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/fir
ebase-tools\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hidakarento/.npm/_logs/2019-05-18T05_42_06_168Z-debug.log
```

試したことは

[【mac】firebaseインストールのすべて - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Masaki_Mori07/items/70693d0be264e2295163)
[npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0　エラーが出てfirebase-toolsのインストールができない - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/53320)

です。
これで現在のエラー文が表示されます。

どなたかご回答いただけると幸いです！！

Comment: `npm`のインストールをsudoで行った疑いがあります。`ls -lah /Users/hidakarento/.npm-global/` や `ls -lah /Users/hidakarento/.npm` の結果を質問文に追記して頂けませんか？　質問文下の「編集」より自由に編集できます :)